# Replacing Ubuntu w/ Win10 using USB - Can't Boot from Win10USB @ Asus Laptop

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bios, reboot, hard-drive-recovery

Summary: I can't boot a Win10 installation USB from my Asus Vivobook Laptop with Ubuntu Linux currently installed.

I have a new Asus VivoBook 14 that came stock with Windows on it.  Out of the box, I replaced the Windows installation with an encrypted Ubuntu 18.04 OS for my dev work. My current specs are:

- Ubuntu 18.04.3
- Processor: IntelCore i7-8565U
- GNOME: 3.28.2 OS
- Type: 64bit

Everything works fine, I have access to the Linux OS, etc etc, but due to some new work-related tech, I now need to switch back to Windows 10 (VM is not ideal).  I have downloaded a Windows ISO and made a bootable USB, but when I try to reboot and select the USB, it's not detected.  The BIOS settings sees the drive but I can't select it as a boot option.  Below are some photos of my laptop settings along with what the bios looks like:

[Ubuntu Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9B3x.jpg)

[Boot Menu Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwW1e.jpg)

[Bios Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfmkt.jpg)

I have made sure that Secure Boot is off and Fast Boot is off as well. I read somewhere that CMS settings need to be turned on, but I don't have that option in my boot menu. Also, I am unable to add my USB as a boot option from the BIOS menu:
[Advanced Settings p1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw3JB.jpg)

[Advanced Settings p2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2mbW.jpg)

[Advanced Settings p3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQko2.jpg)

Lastly, following another thread, I tried to set my boot from the grub CLI, but I received errors doing that.  Results can be seen here:
[Grub Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7kB5.jpg)

Here is a snap of the bootable USB, as that might be an issue, but it looks right to me:

[Win10 Boot USB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wyw5.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been grinding on this all day and no luck.  Thanks!

Comment: You can dual-boot and that's likely the safest option considering you don't know much about what you're doing. But either way you need to 1. make a correct USB installation media and 2. learn how to boot from it in the specific machine. For #1 preferably use the official Media Creation Tool, in Windows (newer Microsoft ISOs are tricky and may not boot if done with some tools that used to work). And you need to boot in UEFI mode so no, do NOT turn on CSM/Legacy.

Comment: I have valid USB installation media, as mentioned in my post.  I am here because I can't boot it from my specific machine.  Please reread the post.

Comment: *I have valid USB installation media* No, you probably don't, as hinted in the comment.

Comment: I am able to boot from the same USB on two other machines without a problem.

Comment: Are those BIOS or UEFI? That's usually the issue.

Comment: UEFI. They are both running the same Ubuntu Linux 18.04 distro.

Comment: The installed OS or none is irrelevant. I suspect you've made a USB suitable for BIOS boots only and in the two UEFI machines where it works the firmware settings allow for CSM/Legacy/"BIOS". Mentioned in the question is *I read somewhere that CMS settings need to be turned on, but I don't have that option in my boot menu* so this one can't boot in "BIOS mode". Please check your firmware settings in the other machines to confirm or disprove this hypothesis.

Comment: The other machines have an option to turn on CSM and it is set to enabled.  The USB was made by following the link here: https://www.onetransistor.eu/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html

Comment: Can you reinstall Windows from the Restore feature, then reinstall Ubuntu later?

Comment: Before removing Windows 10, did you create a recovery disc, UBS or other image? If you reset your machine to factory you will probably end up with Windows 8.1. Just read the specs and help from Factory Restore at the ASUS (U.S.A.).

Comment: Thanks for confirming the hypotheses. That guide is old and I already commented about it in the first one. The current Microsoft ISOs somehow break the standard and don't boot, at least in UEFI mode, if not done with the official tool in Windows (MKUSB in Ubuntu has been reported to work too - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive (do read the notes, please)).

Comment: New Windows ISO are now over 4GB (the .wim file), so you now cannot use FAT32. Suggestion is usually use exFAT which is not normally installed in Ubuntu, but can be.